# Suitescript that should auto populate the custom field(Primary Contact & Primary Email) when a customer field in sales record is entered by a value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, erp, suitescript2.0

Primary contact and email information should be retrieved from the particular customer, mentioned in the sales order.

I tried the below code, but I'm unable to retrieve the role (Primary Contact) from Customer Record. I'm getting null value(empty) while entering the customer field in sales order and also not auto-populating the custom fields.

```
function fieldChanged(context) 
    {

        var sales=context.currentRecord;

        if(context.fieldId=='entity')
        {
            var cusid=sales.getValue('entity');

            var cust=record.load({
                type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                id:cusid
            });

            var custid=cust.getText('entityid');

            log.debug(custid);


            var roleCount= cust.getLineCount({
                sublistId :'contactroles',

            });

            log.debug('count',roleCount);

            for(var i=0;i<roleCount;i++)
            {
                var roleName=cust.getSublistText({ sublistId : 'contactroles',fieldId : 'contactrole', line:i});

                log.debug('role',roleName);

                if(roleName=='Primary Contact')
                {
                    var emailinfo=cust.getSublistText({ sublistId : 'contactroles',fieldId : 'email', line:i});
                    sales.setValue('custbody_primary_email',emailinfo);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference a customer field 'contact'. This field will give you the internal id of primary contact. From there you can build a logic to get the information out of the primary contact.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fieldChanged(context) {
  try {
    var sales = context.currentRecord;
    if (context.fieldId == 'entity') //checking whether the cursor is in customer field or not
     {
      var cusid = sales.getValue('entity'); //retrieving the id of customer in salesOrder

      var cust = record.load({     //loading the customer record using above id
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
        id: cusid
      });

      log.debug('customer id', cusid);

      var custid = cust.getText('entityid');

      log.debug(custid);


      var roleCount = cust.getLineCount({  //counting the lines in sublist (customer record)
        sublistId: 'contactroles'

      });

      log.debug('count', roleCount);

      for (var i = 0; i < roleCount; i++)   //traversing the list in sublist(contact list)
      {
        var roleId = cust.getSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'contactroles',
          fieldId: 'contact',
          line: i
        });

        log.debug('role id', roleId);

        var contactRecord = record.load({   //loading the contact record
          type: record.Type.CONTACT,
          id: roleId
        });

        var roleName = contactRecord.getValue({     //fetching the role in contact record
          fieldId: 'contactrole'
        });

        var phone1 = contactRecord.getText('phone');

        var emailinfo = contactRecord.getText('email');

        if (roleName == '-10')  //checking whether it is primary contact or not(primary contact id is -10)
         {

          sales.setValue('custbody_primary_email', emailinfo);//setting the custom fields )

          sales.setValue('custbody_primary_contact', phone1);
        }

      }

    }
  } catch (e) {
    log.error('Error Occurred in Updating Values' + e.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `contactrole` field in the `contactroles` sublist. See the [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/customer.html#field_contactroles_) for correct field IDs.

Comment: Yes , that true.. but when i replace that with 'role' , im getting differernt role which is not included in the role list. Actually im supposed to get "Primary Contact'